# Python dictionary for lookup excel

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

i have a lookup excel with file name in column A and its lookup no in Column B

file Name   Recipient List File

reports,txt 1

reports1.txt    2

where reports.txt has email ids for sending mail.

Can you help me in writing a code beyond this, for the values in dictionary is coming in decimal.

```
sheetdict = {}
#build dictionary3
for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
    sheetdict[sheet.cell(rownum, 0).value] = [sheet.cell(rownum,1).value]

for keys, values in sheetdict.items():
  print(keys, values)
```

so if i choose recipient list file 1 , it should automatically open the reports.txt and send mail resp.

Answer (score 0):

Is your issue just that you're getting the answer in decimal? For example, 1.0 instead of 1? It would be good if you could provide an example of your input/output/desired output.

Comment: yes and also how to read a file with dictionary value and open it